# How can I install the cweb-latex package?

Tags: cweb

I do not find the package in MikTeX's package
repository?  (Nobody cares about it?)

I tried a [manual installation](https://ctan.org/pkg/cweb-late),
but in the end I still missed a cweb.sty file which is just not
included in the package, so I was very puzzled.  ``I just don't
know how to install this thing'', I concluded.

Is anyone using cweb-latex on Windows?  How did you do it?
Thank you.

Comment: have not checked my tex live version for that package but there are some that are specific to each distro for many reasons such as combined redundant copyrights etc. It is possible that MiKTeX have concluded that is replaced by other functions or has non windows appeal/features

Comment: If a package on ctan is not in miktex which you think should be there you should add an issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging. Here on tex.sx we can't do nothing about it.